# Cisco - supervisor reset without disabling interfaces

Tags: cisco, redundancy, cisco-4500

After power loss we have an issue with supervisor on 4500~ cisco switch.

```
Peer (slot: 3) information is not available because it is in 'DISABLED' state
```

But interfaces that are in that card are forwarding traffic. 
Is it possible to reboot supervisor card without diabling interfaces attached to it?

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to reboot that card without disabling interfaces? Can I remove that card and plug again without affecting working interfaces?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on the Cisco Catalyst 4500, interfaces located on the supervisor card function independently of the supervisor functionality. It is possible that the supervisor is not running IOS (and may in fact be in rommon), but the interfaces are forwarding traffic just fine under the control of the other supervisor.